# Solr DIH - Small index still take time?

Tags: java, performance, search, solr, lucene

This is the situation, I have two sources of data in my dataimport handler, one is huge, the other is tiny:

```
Source A: 10-20 records 
Source B: 50,000,000 records
```

I was wondering what happens if I was to do a DIH just on Source A every 10 mins, and only run the DIH on source B every 24 hours.

Would running my DIH on Source A be extremely quick, because the data we are importing is small, or would it still be time consuming, because it would have to rebuild the index of the entire SOLR (i.e 50,000,010 records).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about different SOLR cores?

Comment: All on the same core, since I want them to be searched as one, but just get data from two different sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would running my DIH on Source A be extremely quick, because the data
>   we are importing is small, or would it still be time consuming,
>   because it would have to rebuild the index of the entire SOLR (i.e
>   50,000,010 records).

Data Import from Source1 to your Index should be **quick**, provided you update only the **10 - 20 records** rather than **50,000,010 records**.

You could do so by providing entity name during dataimport as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import&entity=Source1
```

Even for these 10 - 20 records , you could do [delta-import](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command) on subsequent calls, after doing an initial [full-import](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example).